# Procedure GET in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure but I'm getting a syntax error.

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Clientes_Get]
    (@Id int)
AS
    SELECT 
        (Id, Nome, CpfCnpj,
         Endereco, Numero, Email,
         DataNascimento, Alergia,
         Observacoes, DataInclusao)
     FROM
         [dbo].[Clientes]
     WHERE
         Id = @Id
```

The error message is:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns in `SELECT` should not be in parentheses.  So:

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    Nome, 
    CpfCnpj,
    Endereco,
    Numero,
    Email,
    DataNascimento,
    Alergia,
    Observacoes,
    DataInclusao
FROM [dbo].[Clientes]
WHERE Id=@Id ;
```

I would suggest that you make this a table-valued function, so you can use it in a query.